# When loading ag-grid tree view, how do we default the first level to be expanded?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

When angular binds the data to the ag-grid we cannot seem to find the correct life-cycle event to bind to in order to force the first row of nodes to be expanded. We can do it if we add an additional timeout, but I try to avoid that hack as often as possible.

As of now, we were hoping to use onGridReady and go through the rowNodes and expand them.

Ideally, I would like to just say something along the lines of

`gridApi.expandLevel(0)`

any thoughts here?

currently using Ag-grid v.17.0.0 & angular 5.2.8

Comment: This has been an issue with ag grid's other configs as well (filter, sort) i.e. Setting up default state for the grid. They fixed it by providing a better event to listen to. https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2709. Your best option might be to upgrade to v19

Comment: If upgrading were a current option, i would. Too many breaking changes.